SSL: EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL: error in rockylinux
I tried connecting to kafka using the sslcontext in python3.11
ssl_context = create_ssl_context(
    cafile="cert.pem",
    certfile="client-cert.pem",
    keyfile="client-key.pem",
    password="<some key>
)

SSl context is created in ubuntu and it is working properly
But if I try the same in RockyLinux with same version of python and same certs, I am getting the below error
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL] ee key too small (_ssl.c:3905)

That this happens on one (unknown) system but not on another (RockyLinux) might be due to different defaults regarding security. Minimum key sizes (as seems to be the problem here) is not defined by Python but in the underlying OpenSSL and in its system configuration.
